# Splunk - Split a field into multiple fields based on delimiters

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I have the following value in a field which needs to be split into multiple fields,

Classname:

```
abc.TestAutomation.NNNN.Specs.Prod/NDisableTransactionalAccessUsers.#()::TestAssembly:abc.TestAutomation
```

Required output:

```
Productname : abc.TestAutomation.NNNN.Specs.Prod

Feature name : NDisableTransactionalAccessUsers

Project : TestAssembly:abc.TestAutomation
```

I have been trying to extract the values into my fields using REX command, but I am failing.

```
source="Reports.csv"  index="prod_reports_data" sourcetype="ReportsData"  
| rex "classname(?<Productname>/*)\.(?<Featurename>#*)\.(?<Project>.*)" 
| table classname Productname Featurename Project
```

While I execute this command, there are no results.  I am very new to Splunk, can someone guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost always use multiple [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) statement to get what I want ... but if you "know" the data is consistent, this will work (tried on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RSqX6R/1)):

```
| rex field=_raw (?<classname>[^\/]+)\/(?<featurename>[^\.]+)\.[[:punct:]]+(?<project>[\w].+)
```

What this regular expression does:

- `<classname>` :: everything from the front of the event to a front slash (`/`)
- `<featurename>` :: whatever follows the front slash (`/`) until a literal dot (`.`)
- discard all found punctuation
- `<project>` :: whatever is left on the line

According to regex101.com, this is *likely* the most efficient rex you can use (14 steps total)

Comment: Thank you! Works right for my requirement.